# Se puede crear algún tipo de lista .bat

Tags: batch

Lo que formulo es lo siguiente ,deseo crear algún tipo de lista, ya que tengo este instalador de impresoras , pero no quiero que pida ip y nombre , si no que los valores ya estén almacenados y los llame ,lo quiero asi porque el usuario no conoce el nombre y seria mas facil para el solo buscarlo,por algún tipo de ciclo o lista,es posible porque veo que es un poco rustico pero cumple su funcion.

```
 title AUTO - INSTALADOR IMPRESORAS  V 0.3

 color 30
 cls
 @echo off

 echo.
 echo.
 echo DIGITE LA IP DE LA IMPRESORA QUE DESEA CONFIGURAR Y PRESIONE "ENTER":

 set /P IP=

 echo DIGITE EL NOMBRE DE LA IMPRESORA Y PRESIONE "ENTER", EJEMPLO:IBMDE11BLM1

 set /P NOMBRE=

 cscript %windir%\SysWOW64\Printing_Admin_Scripts\es-ES\prnport.vbs -a -r %IP% -h %IP% -o  raw -n 9100 -me
 pause
 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "%NOMBRE%" /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef\lmud1p40.inf" /r %IP% /m "Lexmark Universal v2" /u
 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%NOMBRE%"
 rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /e /n "%NOMBRE%"
 echo SE INSTALO CORRECTAMENTE "ENTER" 
 pause
 exit
```

Comment: ¿Deseas que el usuario seleccione la impresora de una lista o en este caso desde un menú en pantalla? Es lo que entiendo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Desde un menú en pantalla así, digamos algo así como cuando en html uno crea una lista

Comment: Hace muuuuucho tiempo que no programo en `batch files` ten una idea que la última vez que lo hice era para realizar un proceso de instalación de Windows 95. Mi programa mostraba varias pantallas para ir guiando al usuario en el proceso previo a la instalación. Déjame desempolvar un par de diskettes y veo si tengo algo que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias es que es la única manera que encontré de instalar una impresora, sin utilizar permisos de administrador

Comment: Ojo, que lo que vas a hacer es mostrar una lista de opciones al usuario, normalmente numeradas, el usuario introduce el número correspondiente al valor deseado de la lista, como cuando vas un restaurant y pides el plato número 3. Eso es lo que vas a capturar y de acuerdo al número introducido el programa seguirá la configuración.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dije en mi comentario, hace ya mucho tiempo que no programo con `BATCH` para Windows. Realmente lo hacía para `D.O.S.` en la versión 6.2. La solución que te daré aqui usa el antiguo `GOTO`. Tal vez haya alguna manera más eficiente de hacerlo actualmente, sin embargo mi código funciona. (Al menos en Windows 10 64bit donde lo probé).

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear algún tipo de lista donde el usuario realice una elección para poder instalar una impresora en sistema operativo (Windows). Ya se ha impelementado la instalación, pero requiere de la intervención del usuario para poner nombre de impresora y dirección IP. Se desea simplificar este paso mediante la lista de opciones.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la tarea, se creará un menú que mostrará los nombres de las impresoras junto a su dirección IP asignada. El usuario solo debe seleccionar el número correspondiente a la impresora deseada de la lista.

De acuerdo a la selección del usuario se configurarán los valores de las variables `NOMBRE` e `IP`.

Una vez que se hayan establecido las variables, se continuará con el proceso de instalación.

Se usa el 'antiguo' pero efectivo `GOTO`.

```
title AUTO - INSTALADOR IMPRESORAS  V 0.3

 color 30
 cls
 @echo off

:menu
 cls
 echo.
 echo.
 echo #### IMPRESORAS DISPONIBLES ####
 echo.
 echo.
 echo 1.- IBMDE11BLM1 - 192.168.0.100
 echo 2.- HPLJ2345CAF - 192.168.0.101
 echo 3.- XEROXLJ45CU - 192.168.0.102
 echo.
 echo DIGITE EL NUMERO DE LA IMPRESORA Y PRESIONE "ENTER", PARA SALIR DIGITE "X"

 set /P IMPRESORA=

 IF %IMPRESORA%==1 goto impresora1
 IF %IMPRESORA%==2 goto impresora2
 IF %IMPRESORA%==3 goto impresora3
 IF %IMPRESORA%==X goto salida
 IF %IMPRESORA%==x goto salida
 goto menu

:impresora1
 SET NOMBRE=IBMDE11BLM1
 SET IP=192.168.0.100
 goto instalador

:impresora2
 SET NOMBRE=HPLJ2345CAF
 SET IP=192.168.0.101
 goto instalador

:impresora3
 SET NOMBRE=XEROXLJ45CU
 SET IP=192.168.0.102
 goto instalador

:instalador
 echo.
 echo SE INSTALARA LA IMPRESORA %NOMBRE% CON LA IP %IP%
 echo.
 pause
 cscript %windir%\SysWOW64\Printing_Admin_Scripts\es-ES\prnport.vbs -a -r %IP% -h %IP% -o  raw -n 9100 -me
 pause
 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "%NOMBRE%" /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef\lmud1p40.inf" /r %IP% /m "Lexmark Universal v2" /u
 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%NOMBRE%"
 rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /e /n "%NOMBRE%"
 echo SE INSTALO CORRECTAMENTE "ENTER"
 pause

:salida
 cls
 echo.
 echo HASTA LUEGO
 echo.
 pause
 exit
```

Vemos en el código anterior que el el usuario debe elegir de una lista de opciones. Si el usuario teclea cualquier dígito diferente de los ya establecidos, el menú se repite. Para salir se le pide al usuario que presione `X`, el programa captura tanto el caso mayúscula como minúscula.

Cada etiqueta `:impresorax` configura las variables `NOMBRE` e `IP`. y usa el comando `GOTO` para ir hasta la etiqueta `:instalador`, donde está la lógica para la instalación.

Finalmente hay una etiqueta `:salida`, la cual será la última parte del código que se ejecutará en nuestro archivo `batch`.

Espero que esta solución te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Tienes razón, corregiré el problema. Gracias por la sugerencia.